# runOnUiTHread code not executing

Tags: android, android-asynctask

For some reason code that I have in a runOnUiThread call seems to not execute:

```
        ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG,"createAndDisplayDialog - Start dialog");
                progressDialog = new MyDialog(ctx);  
                progressDialog.show();
                Log.d(TAG,"createAndDisplayDialog - Started dialog");
            }
        });
```

The dialog is simply not displayed.

However, to confuse things even more it does work in certain cases but not others.

What we have is a list with data. The list includes a "Get more data" button. The onclick listener then calls code to fetch more data and adds it to the list that is used by the Adapter.
When I fill the first lot of data it is fetched within the previous activity and then sent to the displaying activity for diplay in a List via the adapter.
The dialog DOES display in that case.
However, when I ask for more data, which runs through the same code as used when fetching the original set of data, the dialog is no longer displayed.

In both cases, the fetching of the data is does in an AsyncTask. The data arrives ok but the dialog simply doesn't show.

To confuse matters more, we have other screens where the data is not fetched in advance. Instead the adapter does all the work - fetching the original data and any more data asked for. In this case the dialog appears without any problem.

I'm probably missing something simple but just can't seem to find it.

Comment: Why do you need to run this code inside the doInBackground? If you want to show a dialog for the whole process, you should do it inside the onPreExecute, if you want to show it at some later moment, you should use onProgressUpdate.

Comment: @Waqas It would mean posting a whole ton of code. Not so easy to get the feew lines out

Comment: @Egor The thing is that the decision as to whether to show the dialog or not is not made by the same code that starts the background task. The task could be started in the background when the data is fetched or could be sent there much earlier. That's why I have to do it within the background and send it via the runOnUi. The weird thing is that the first time it is run it does work and it is also in the background.

Comment: @njzk2 The logcat clearly shows that those two log commands do not apear. The runOnUiThread command itself is definitelty executed.

Comment: there is not enough code here to know what goes wrong

Comment: @njzk2 My mistake. The two lines "Start dialog" and "Started dialog" DO appear in the LogCat.

Comment: @Egor I tried moving it into the preexecute but still the same result. It just refuses to show it.